# Months Between 2 dates for each Project

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am trying to run a query to return a row for each month between 2 dates for each project that I have. See example data:

```
Project  Start      End
1        1/1/2015   3/1/2015
2        2/1/2015   4/1/2015
```

End Data needed:

```
Project  Month
1        1/1/2015
1        2/1/2015
1        3/1/2015
2        2/1/2015
2        3/1/2015
2        4/1/2015
```

I have several projects and will need a query to do this for all of them at the same time. How can I do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is a CROSS APPLY with an ad-hoc tally table

```
Select A.Project
      ,Month = B.D
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(MONTH,A.Start,A.[End])+1) D=DateAdd(Month,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By(Select null)),A.Start) 
                 From  master..spt_values 
             ) B
```

Returns

```
Project Month
1       2015-01-01
1       2015-02-01
1       2015-03-01
2       2015-02-01
2       2015-03-01
2       2015-04-01
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple if you have or create a table for Months:

```
create table dbo.Months([Month] date primary key);
declare @StartDate     date = '20100101'
       ,@NumberOfYears int  = 30;

insert dbo.Months([Month],MonthEnd)
  select top (12*@NumberOfYears) 
      [Month] = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
  from master.dbo.spt_values;
```

If you really do not want to have a Months table, you can use a `cte` like this:

```
declare @StartDate     date = '20100101'
       ,@NumberOfYears int  = 10;

;with Months as (
  select top (12*@NumberOfYears) 
    [Month] = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate)
  from master.dbo.spt_values
)
```

Then query it like so:

```
select 
    t.Project
  , m.Month
from t
  inner join dbo.Months m
    on m.Month >= t.Start
   and m.Month <= t.[End]
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SXPX26360

returns:

```
+---------+------------+
| Project |   Month    |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 2015-01-01 |
|       1 | 2015-02-01 |
|       1 | 2015-03-01 |
|       2 | 2015-02-01 |
|       2 | 2015-03-01 |
|       2 | 2015-04-01 |
+---------+------------+
```

calendar and numbers tables reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops 2- Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

Answer (score 1):

I personally like a tally table for this kind of thing. It is the swiss army knife of t-sql.

I create a view on my system for this. If you don't want to create a view you can easily use these ctes anytime you need a tally table.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now we just need your sample data in a table.

create table #Projects
(
    Project int
    , Start datetime
    , EndDate datetime
)

insert #Projects
select 1, '1/1/2015', '3/1/2015' union all
select 2, '2/1/2015', '4/1/2015'

At this point we get to the real issue here which is retrieving your information. With the sample data and the view this becomes pretty simple.

```
select p.*
    , NewMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, t.N - 1, p.Start)
from #Projects p
join cteTally t on t.N <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, p.Start, p.EndDate) + 1
order by p.Project
    , t.N
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate Time [series](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho) take help from the link.

Then join time using between

SELECT --something
FROM table1 a
/*type of*/ JOIN table2 b ON  b.field2 BETWEEN a.field2 AND a.field3